# smartgwt filter setData

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have a grid that is filled by the setData method, I create a filter but I see that the filter that comes with the default grid works, when I obtained the data through a DataSource class, but I did not do well, I did it with a simple setData

There is way to implement a filter without using Datasources?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this forum post](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=22009), I tend to doubt that you can filter without a DataSource.  I suggest constructing a DataSource and calling setClientOnly() on this ListGrid to prevent it from firing any CRUD events.